# Get continuously location only when moving using Network provider

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

I am getting location coordinates from Network provider(GSM), but the time interval between each location update is very long, which make my route display of the user using these points  very vague. i tried

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

which results in continuous update even the device not moving, but when moving updates are coming in long interval only, which i do not required.

So i tried

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);
```

and now i am getting coordinate update in very long interval. 
I read that the TIME_DURATION, DISTANCE are only a hint to the location manager. 
Please tell a way to get the location update from NETWORK_PROVIDER in 1 min interval, only when the device is moving.